# How to push a sequence of html pages after one request using NodeJS and ExpressJS

Tags: node.js, express

I am turning around in stackoverflow without finding an answer to my question. I have used expressJS fur several days in order to make an access webpage that returns first an interstitial and then a webpage depending on several informations I can get from the requester IP and so on.

My first idea for the interstitial was to use this piece of code:

```
var interstitial = function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('interstitial');
    next();
}

router.get('/', interstitial, nextPage);
```

setting a timeout on the next nextPage callback function of router.get().

However it looks that I could not do that. I had an error "Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.". I suppose this is due to the fact that res.render already give a response to the request and in the philosophy of express, the next function is passing the req, res args for another reply to another function that possibly could do it. Am I right?

In that case, is there a way to give several answer, with timeout to one request? (a res.render, and after that in the next callback a rest.send...).
Or is this mandatory to force client to ask a request to give back another response? (using js on the client side for instance, or timers on client side, or maybe discussing with client script using socket.io).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I fully understand, but you should be placing all your deterministic logic within the function of the handler you're using for your endpoint.

Kinda like so:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res){
  var origin = request.origin;
  if (origin == '11.22.33.44'){
    res.send('Interstitial Page.');
  }else{
    res.send('Home Page');
  }
});
```

You would replace the simple text responses with your actual pages, but the general idea is that once that endpoint is handled you can't `next()` it to secondary handler.